# Outputted results from query outputting, but not allowing some of the results to be selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have the following code that is supposed to shuffle results from my database if a user is in group 3, 4 or 5. The query is outputting the results fine, but when I click the button to shuffle the results, the only results that display then are from group 3. I believe the issue in my JS, but I'm not sure where or why it is only shuffling the group 3 results when my query is selecting all users from group 3,4 and 5 and the output shows that.

Lets say:

Bob is group 3

Joe is group 4.

Bill is group 5

---

The way my page looks is like this.

Users that need shuffled...
-Bob
-Joe
-Bill

Button - Shuffle

When I click on the Shuffle Button. Only Bob shows up.

What is wrong in my code that would do this?

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` IN (3, 4 ,5)");

echo 'Users to be given draft order: <br>';
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
}
?>
<form method="POST" name="form">
    <input type="submit" value="Create Draft Order" name="shuffle">
</form>

    Shuffled results: <br>
    <div class="main-bag">     
    <div class="shuffle_results" id="results"></div> 
    </div>       
     <form method="post">
         <input type="submit" value="Finalize Draft Order" name="insert">

var displayResults = function(data){
    var i = 0;
    var lineheight = 24;
    var time = 3000;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
        if( i <= data.length){ 
            console.log( data[i] ); 
            $('#results').append('<div class="result">' +
                        //'<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                        '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].drafted_order + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                        '<input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="' + data[i].drafted_order + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="' + data[i].firstname + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="' + data[i].lastname + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' + data[i].id + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="' + data[i].username + '">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="' + data[i].email + '">' +
                    '</div>');
           var $this = $('.shuffle_results:last'); 
            $this.show().animate({ 
                'left': 0 + 'px', 
                'bottom': + '0px' 
                //$(document).height() - (lineheight * data.length)
            }, { 
                duration: time 
            });
        i++;
        } else { 
            clearInterval(interval); 
        } 
    }, 3000); 
};
```

Comment: Are they supposed to be randomly shuffled so the order changes?

Comment: Yes. Just the group 4 and 5 users do not get shuffled and re-outputted.

Comment: Is it supposed to shuffle in place like: `Dave (g1), Doug  (g3), Don (g2), Shane (g5), Frank (g2), Mark (g4)` then shuffles like `Dave (g1), Shane (g5), Don (g2), Mark (g4), Frank (g2), Doug (g3)` so it keeps the placement order of the total list but just shuffles names in between non-shuffled?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. My first output I have is just listing the users who will be shuffled. The shuffle part works correctly in that it shuffles the names. I have had many names in group 3 before, I just never tested group 4 or 5 because I thought it worked. So this isn't including group 4/5 in the shuffles results.

Comment: Look at this fiddle, it shuffles, but it doesn't intersperse shuffled and non-shuffled:  https://jsfiddle.net/yzdojre2/  That is to say, it does not keep the total order of shuffle and non-shuffle. It groups them, top shuffles, bottom static.

Comment: I want all users to be shuffled.